# If Else Statement - Jquery Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, if-statement

Bit of a JQuery beginner - trying to animate a "tab" to follow the class "StaffPanel" as it animates outwards.

Below are my scripts.  The second one works properly, animating the class outwards and attaching the .StaffTriggerActive to the button.

Problem is,  I can't seem to figure out how to write a if else statement to make the button animate to the closed state once the user closes the button..

I obviously am doing something wrong - any one with ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.StaffTrigger').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('.StaffTriggerActive')) {
                $(".StaffTriggerActive").animate ({
                right: '=0'
                }, "fast"); 
        }
        else {
                $(".StaffTriggerActive").animate ({
                right: '=340'
                }, "fast");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".StaffTrigger").click(function(){

    $(".StaffPanel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("StaffTriggerActive");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you have two document ready? I think you are looking for callback function to handle things after completion?

Comment: Nevermind.  Bit of a blonde today.. Combined them both into the single if else script :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasClass` method can't have the **.** on the class name. Just do this way:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('StaffTriggerActive')) ...
```